# Graph API returning 403 forbidden from 18th Mar 2019

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

The Following implementation works perfectly till 18th Mar 2019.

```
var graphClient = this.graphService.GraphClient;
var reqUrl = graphClient
    .Me
    .Request()
    .RequestUrl;
reqUrl += "/findMeetingTimes";
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
    { { "Prefer", $"outlook.timezone = \"{parameter.PreferredTimeZone}\"" },
    };

var noOfMeetingSlots = parameter.MaxCandidates ?? 5;

parameter.MaxCandidates = 25;

var hrm = this.graphService.CreateHttpPostRequest<MeetingSuggestionParameter>(
    parameter,
    new Uri(reqUrl),
    headers);

await graphClient
    .AuthenticationProvider
    .AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

MeetingSuggestionResult result = null;

try
{
    using(HttpResponseMessage response = await graphClient
            .HttpProvider
            .SendAsync(hrm)
            .ConfigureAwait(false)) {
```

Exception:

```
graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync throws 403 Forbidden. 
Exception Message:
Code: UnknownError

Inner error

StackTrace 
at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Publicis.Marcel.Services.Calendar.CalendarService.FindMeetingSuggesstionsWithParametersAsync(MeetingSuggestionParameter parameter) in E: \Assistant2\o365\Services\Publicis.Marcel.Services.Calendar\Concrete\CalendarService.cs:line
```

The following snippet does work using Client SDK:

```
var re = await graphClient
    .Me
    .FindMeetingTimes(
        Attendees,
        null,
        null,
        new Duration(parameter.MeetingDuration),
        parameter.MaxCandidates,
        parameter.IsOrganizerOptional,
        parameter.ReturnSuggestionReasons,
        parameter.MinimumAttendeePercentage)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Things I've already checked

1. Azure AD service-principal permission. It does have `caledar.read` and  `calendar.read.Shared`

This was working in production till 18th Mar 2019 when it started throwing the `403 Forbidden`.

Comment: What is stopping you from switching to the working snippet? That code is what I would expect to see in this case. Unless you have a very specific need (i.e. calling a beta API), you really shouldn't need to use `HttpProvider`. It's a fallback for certain scenarios but this doesn't look like one of them.

Comment: The Implementation is already in production. Need to understand What has changed before making the change.  This was an working code, unless anything changed from Graph SDK. Why Would it give 503 after Mar18th?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to know for sure. A `403` generally means your token isn't valid (missing scopes, expired, wrong resource, etc). If you can add the bearer token from the most recent error and the time (in UTC) that failure happened, that might help.

Comment: Here is the access token. Its failing constantly not specific to any time.

Comment: I don't see the token added to your question.